# Add error to New Relic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

Our application has plenty of `rescue` blocks in worker threads. Exceptions are logged, but thread continues working - that's the point. Now I have added New Relic to the app, but the `Errors -> Events' page is always empty although there are errors in app logs.

Is there some way to add error to New Relic manually, in `rescue` block, without re-raising an exception?

Answer (score 3):

The agent only reports up the unhandled exceptions.  Not capturing the handled exceptions is the expected behavior. In order to see these handled exceptions you should be able to use the New Relic Ruby API call notice_error() which is described here:

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/newrelic/rpm/NewRelic/Agent#notice_error-instance_method

Comment: What if I remove New Relic from Gemfile? How could I write the code which does not need to be updated whether newrelic is in Gemfile or not?

Comment: @Paul Put your notice_error inside an `if defined? NewRelic` conditional.

Comment: Although notice_error method is executed successfully, no errors appear in New Relic web console. Exceptions not caught by me appear there as they should.

Comment: @avital: No. I wasn't.